# Can CXF produce SOAP responses that do not comply to the WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am using CXF for SOAP Webservices. Is there any situation where the resulting SOAP response does not conform to the WSDL? I let CXF generate the code from the WSDL via wsdl2java.

For example I have some entity with `minOccurs=1`. Will CXF enforce that the corresponding Java element will not be null?

Are other discrepancies possible?

An example: I have the following WSDL type:

```
     <xsd:complexType name="PropertyList">
        <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" name="property" 
                        type="pms-xsd:Property" />
        </xsd:sequence>
     </xsd:complexType>
```

which gets translated to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PropertyList", propOrder = {
    "property"
})
public class PropertyList {

  @XmlElement(required = true)
  protected List<Property> property;
...
```

This, to my understanding, requires for the List `property` to exist (in the form of an XmlElement), but not that at least one Property exists, which the WSDL requires. Is this a possible problem, or am I understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To enforce the schema you need to enable schema validation. Please check [here](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?) to enable schema validation. A sample code snippet shown below.

```
 <jaxws:endpoint name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort"
    wsdlLocation="wsdl/hello_world.wsdl"
    createdFromAPI="true">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

**Note:** In order to work you need to set wsdl location properly. Such that during schema validation WSDL file gets referred.

Comment: This only refers to schema validation, which tests the responses against the supplied wsdl. I am more talking about the problem that the generated SOAP response may not even validate and if that will already be ensured by the marshalling process by honoring for example the minOccurs attribute.

Comment: There are not JAXB specific validation annotations, even while marshalling/unmarshalling in JAXB we provide the xsd file against which schema validation will be applied. In CXF before marshalling schema validation will be applied in one of the in-phase. and out message schema validation is applied in one of the out-phase after unmarshalling phase. during schema validation if it fails, it will throw error.